# how to access buttons events from controller objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I just started to learn Objective-C and iPhone SDK programming. I have made 2 rect buttons and one label in my XIB design (it is appearing after clicking on views). I have to make code in button click event in my controller. As in c#.net we simply take button.click event (dummy code).

Like I have 2 rect buttons and their title is 8 and 9 and one label. When I will click on button 8 my label will print 8 and similarly when I will click on button 9 my label will show 9. My concern is that is how will know in controller (.m file) which button is being pressed.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `tag` field of your buttons to different values, then define a method

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;
```

and inside it call `[(UIView *)sender tag]`. Checking that value you will know what button has been pressed.

Alternatively you may call two different methods, but since the behavior is such similar I'd prefer the first solution.

Comment: You will actually have to typecast that sender towards an `UIView *` to be able to retrieve a `tag` value; `[(UIView *)id tag];`

Comment: Conceptually you're right (if you cast `sender` not `id`), I just forgot to cast it. It works the same though. :)